# Missing a using directive or an assembly reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-directives, assembly-references

Looks like I am missing a using directive or an assembly reference.

I made a CSHTML page to show a bill to user. this is made as an empty page using TBL_Bill table. but I encounter an error while trying to read data from other tables such as Tbl_Product for products. The error tells me

> Tbl_Bill does not contain a definition for Tbl_Product and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type Tbl_Bill could be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<fardashahr3.Models.Domain.Tbl_Bill>
@using fardashahr3.Models.Repository
@using fardashahr3.Models.Plugins

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "sales";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Profile.cshtml";
}

<div class="part_left">
    <div id="product_list" class="userpanel_bright_section">
        @if (ViewBag.Error != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <a class="close" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="$('.alert').hide()">×</a>
                @ViewBag.Error
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <h1 class="separator"> شماره فاکتور  : @Model.InvoiceNumber</h1>

            if (Model.Tbl_Product.Product_IsDownload == false)
            {
                <div class="table_style1" id="UpIBill">
```

Comment: This is not your real code, because your model is an `IEnumerable`, but you are accessing it as a single item. Also, post your Tbl_Bill class for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what do you mean by this is not my real code?

Comment: If Model is an IEnumerable<Tbl_bill>, there is no property Tbl_Product, but I'd expect the exception to say something like 'IEnumerable<Tbl_Bill> does not contain a definition for Tbl_Product'.

Answer (score 1):

according to the error you posted, it seems your model that you are using in the view (`@model IEnumerable<fardashahr3.Models.Domain.Tbl_Bill>`) is not having products details (`Tbl_Product`) inside of it to access them using the model in your markup (`Model.Tbl_Product.Product_IsDownload`). Check your model properties and pass the right model into your View.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Model is an `IEnumerable<...>`, you need to iterate over it:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var bill in Model)
    {
        <h1 class="separator"> شماره فاکتور  : @bill.InvoiceNumber</h1>

        if (bill.Tbl_Product.Product_IsDownload == false)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

It's impossible to say from here if `bill.Tbl_Product` is the proper name to use for that property, but this should probably be enough to get you on your way.

Or if each `bill` has a **collection** of products, then you will need to do something like

```
foreach (var product in bill.Products)
{
}
```